# K6 how run node command in the setup function

Tags: javascript, k6

Please excuse my limited K6/Javascript knowledge.

I have been given a javascript file that can be used to create a batch of users to be used within my k6 load test.

The script is currently ran from the commmand line using this command:

```
node helpers/createUsers.js 10
```

I want to run this script in the 'setup' function in K6.

Can I run node commands directly in K6 as above, or do I have to turn it into an export function and then call it?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot run nodeJS or any nodeJS modules directly from a k6 test script. If the script `helpers/createUsers.js` is using any node modules, then you should follow [this](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules#bundling-node-modules). and have the script in the `setup()` function.